# powershell function not working right when used in custom module

Tags: powershell

My function is simple, it connects you to an Office365 account:

```
Function Connect-O365 {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
    $url = "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell"
    $O365Credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your Office 365 Credentials"
    $O365Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $url -Credential $O365Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession -Session $O365Session -Prefix O365
}
```

When running from a custom module, the commands from the imported session are not imported, no message is returned back with any errors or anything.

However, if i copy/paste the same function to my powershell profile, or direct to the console, it works perfectly fine, the commands are successfully imported from the session.

Thoughts?

EDIT: My Module I am adding this function to is a simple .psm1 file with only two other unrelated functions in it, nothing too complex either.

Comment: Have you exported the function in the module?

Comment: Works OK on PS4, what version are you on? What are the errors and which commands from imported session are run? After running `Connect-O365` can you see the module in list?

Comment: modified the last line in my function to:

Import-Module (Import-PSSession -Session $O365Session) -Global -Prefix O365

This resolved my issue, it was that the module was not importing on my Import-Session

Comment: @EvanYoung - good stuff, post that as an answer and accept it so the question can be closed.

Comment: thanks for the help, it lead me to the path of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

modified the last line in my function to:

`Import-Module (Import-PSSession -Session $O365Session) -Global -Prefix O365`

This resolved my issue, it was that the module was not importing on my Import-Session